# Can I utilize indexes when querying by MongoDB subdocument without known field names?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, schema-design

I have a document structure like follows:

```
{
    "_id": ...,
    "name": "Document name",
    "properties": {
        "prop1": "something",
        "2ndprop": "other_prop",
        "other3": ["tag1", "tag2"],
    }
}
```

I can't know the actual field names in `properties` subdocument (they are given by the application user), so **I can't create** indexes like `properties.prop1`. Neither can I know the structure of the field values, they can be single value, embedded document or array.

**Is there any practical way to do performant queries to the collection with this kind of schema design?**

One option that came to my mind is to add a new field to the document, index it and set used field names per document into this field.

```
{
    "_id": ...,
    "name": "Document name",
    "properties": {
        "prop1": "something",
        "2ndprop": "other_prop",
        "other3": ["tag1", "tag2"],
    },
    "property_fields": ["prop1", "2ndprop", "other3"]
}
```

Now I could first run query against `property_fields` field and after that let MongoDB scan through the found documents to see whether `properties.prop1` contains the required value. This is definitely slower, but could be viable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of dealing with this is to use schema like below.

```
{
    "name" : "Document name",
    "properties" : [
        {
            "k" : "prop1",
            "v" : "something"
        },
        {
            "k" : "2ndprop",
            "v" : "other_prop"
        },
        {
            "k" : "other3",
            "v" : "tag1"
        },
        {
            "k" : "other3",
            "v" : "tag2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can index "properties.k" and "properties.v" for example like this:

```
db.foo.ensureIndex({"properties.k": 1, "properties.v": 1})
```

Comment: This solution looks very promiainf. Is there a reason why other3 was in two different subdocuments instead ["tag2", "tag3"]?

Comment: Because it is easier to work with consistent schema. {k: "other3", v: ["tag1", "tag2"]} should work as well although it will be harder to perform some operations like retrieving individual values using aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Eh - why did my "promising" change to "promiainf" in my original comment? Autocomplete, I like it. ;) Thanks for your further comment, this is definitely a great answer to my question.

Comment: One more question came to my mind about this answer. If I do `db.foo.ensureIndex({"properties.k": 1, "properties.v": 1})`, what happens with the query `{"properties.k":"prop1", "properties.v":"tag2"}`. This matches the document, even tag2 is not value of field `prop1`. I may need to explicitly check the document contents from search results?

Comment: Well, it seems that `$elemMatch` is what is needed here. Seems that MongoDB is able to use the mentioned index structure in that case too.